# Wordpress membership site for a sports club

Tags: membership

I am currently building a webpage for a local sports club with 800 members. The features I need in a potential membership plugin is:

1. Member database with name, address, email, phone etc
2. Able to sort the members in different sport categories (football, athletics etc) and subcategories (youth, senior etc).
3. Online payment of annual membership fee.

There are a lot of plugins available, but with slightly different features, so I would appreciate if someone has some insight in plugins that could match my requirements.

Or do I really have to learn how to create custom posts? :)

Comment: This question may get closed as its not really a problem and should be handled by a Google query or any of the other membership site questions here. However I have used WP WishList Member Plugin multiple times and it should meet your needs. Have you done your own research? Possibly email the plugin creators? Otherwise if you go down the custom post route and need help people will happily provide it.

Comment: I like this question. Stuff like this is why I come over to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Create custom posts. It's really intimidating at first, but there are great articles out there, and once you start to do it, you'll feel more comfortable doing things yourself and relying on plugins less. It's very empowering.

Answer (score 1):

Try Paid Memberships Pro which is available for free in the WordPress repository:
http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/paid-memberships-pro/

You can create a membership level for each sport. Create a post category for each sport. Lock the categories down by membership level.

You can get further support with that plugin at http://www.paidmembershipspro.com